# Grails pull object from has many

Tags: grails

I am trying to pull all the PostOrder's out where a child instance is present

My domain is as follows:

```
class PostOrder {

String pOrder
Date dateCreated
Picture picture
Post posts
Video video

static hasMany = [children : Child]
}
```

and the method i am trying to use to get the objects is:

```
 def getAllInOrder(Child child){
 def json =   PostOrder.findAllByChildren(child, sort: 'dateCreated', order: 'desc')    as JSON
    return json
}
```

I am just getting sql exceptions from this.
Any Ideas?

also these are my exceptions:

```
util.JDBCExceptionReporter No value specified for parameter 1
errors.GrailsExceptionResolver SQLException occurred when processing request: [GET]    /FYP/profile/appPosts - parameters:
child: 1
No value specified for parameter 1. Stacktrace follows: 
java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 1
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1073)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:987)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:982)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:927)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.checkAllParametersSet(PreparedStatement.java:2595)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.fillSendPacket(PreparedStatement.java:2571)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.fillSendPacket(PreparedStatement.java:2497)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2251)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi$_methodMissing_closure2.doCall(GormStaticApi.groovy:105)
at com.fyp.timeline.ProfileController$$ENmIB8q0.getAllInOrder(ProfileController.groovy:636)
at com.fyp.timeline.ProfileController$$ENmIB8q0.appPosts(ProfileController.groovy:624)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
PostOrder.findAllByChildren(child, [sort: 'dateCreated', order: 'desc'])
```

Although I don't think this will fix your problem entirely because in this instance, child is expected to be a list. Try this:

```
PostOrder.all.findAll{it.children.contains(child)}
```

It seems like there should be a better way to do that, maybe someone else can ring in.

Comment: Anyone with a better approach to this answer ??? I am also stuck in a similar situation